# The given key was not present in the dictionary- PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, dynamics-nav

I'm getting this issue when trying to load/refresh the report, When I clicked the continue the loading wizard starts with an unending state.

[image: Snipped of issue]

I am receiving the dataset from NAV2017, I have tried another dataset from NAV and it works fine, but when I tried with this custom report than I am facing the issue, Would any has an idea how to deal with this, my PowerBI desktop is fully updated, I have gone through some forum but not able to resolve, I have tried to manage the relationship between the table but for this, I need to Refresh the report which leads to the same state.

> When clicking Detail it shows the following message
>
> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
> (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not
> present in the dictionary.    at
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()    at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)    at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.LoadToReportProgress.UpdateProgressFromQueryEvaluator(LoadToModelQueryEvaluatingProgress progress)    at System.Progress`1.InvokeHandlers(Object state)
> ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
> ---------------------------------------- PBIDesktop
> Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 2.93.981.0
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.93.981.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/bin/pbidesktop.exe
> ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows
> Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 2.93.981.0
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.93.981.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/bin/Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.DLL
> ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Shared
> Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 2.93.981.0
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.93.981.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/bin/Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Shared.DLL
> ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI
> Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 2.93.981.0
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.93.981.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/bin/Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.DLL
> ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.Mashup.Document
> Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 2.93.981.0
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.93.981.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/bin/Microsoft.Mashup.Document.DLL
> ---------------------------------------- System
> Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
> ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.PowerBI.ASCommon
> Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 2.93.981.0
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.93.981.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/bin/Microsoft.PowerBI.ASCommon.DLL
> ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.MashupEngine
> Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 2.93.981.0
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.93.981.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/bin/Microsoft.MashupEngine.DLL
> ..........................
> ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.PowerBI.DataShaping.Processing
> Assembly Version: 13.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 13.0.16000.25
> CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.93.981.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/bin/Microsoft.PowerBI.DataShaping.Processing.DLL
> ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.PowerBI.DataShaping.DataShapeQueryGeneration
> Assembly Version: 13.0.0.0
> Win32 Version: 13.0.16000.25
> CodeBase:
> file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftPowerBIDesktop_2.93.981.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/bin/Microsoft.PowerBI.DataShaping.DataShapeQueryGeneration.DLL
>
> JIT Debugging
>
> To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
> application or computer (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging
> value set in the system.windows.forms section. The application must
> also be compiled with debugging enabled. When JIT debugging is
> enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to the JIT debugger
> registered on the computer rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Comment: What is in `Details`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AndreyNikolov, I have updated the body, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by renaming the Query in PowerQuery. Then I reopened the Transform Data and put the previous name back.

Answer (score 0):

"Error Message:The given key was not present in the dictionary" may be related to a known issue,Icm:219187990.

If the issue is occurring after installing  the update, then Microsoft will release an new update to fix the issue.

Please try follow steps to download and install the latest desktop again.

Launch the Microsoft Store app and look for the Power BI.
Download and install if any update is available for the Power BI App.
Then please using the new version PoweBI desktop to publish the report.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have your cardinality set to either 'one to one' or 'many to one' and the 'unique' column you are joining on has been altered to no longer make it unique.

Delete your relationships that are causing the issue, refresh your data, then reapply your relationships.